# page.save() is not a function - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const addUSDCurrencyToCreatorPage = async () => {
  try {
    const page = await Pages.find({ username });
    console.log("page --", page);
    page.currency = "USD";
    await page.save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I have this script in my Nodejs application where the try to perform the above function i.e. to add `currency` to the document.

When I run this script I get this error.

> page.save() is not a function

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Page** returned from the `find()` callback will be **an array** of mongoose documents, hence the error `page.save() is not a function`.

Since `page` is an array you can use `map()` function like this:

```
page.map(async (p) => {
    p.currency = "USD";
    await p.save();
});
```

**OR**

Either use the `findOne()` method which returns **a single** Mongoose document that has the save method or use `findOneAndUpdate()` for an **atomic** update. [Read more here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

**Example with findOneAndUpdate():**

```
const addUSDCurrencyToCreatorPage = async () => {
  try {
    const page =  await Pages.findOneAndUpdate({username},{ 'currency', 'USD' } }, { new: true }).exec();
   // If `new` isn't true, `findOneAndUpdate()` will return the document as it was before it was updated.
    console.log("page --", page);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: What if I do 
```
const pages = await Pages.find({});
for (let page of pages) { page.currency = "USD"; page.save() }
```
Will this work?

Comment: @vaibhavdeep Yes, it will work too. Use await with `save()`